# Averaging vectors that are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a collection of (random) vectors $\theta_1 \cdots \theta_N$, where the pairwise correlations are close to 0, i.e.

$cor(\theta_i, \theta_j) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$

Can you say anything about the average of a sample of thetas? Given a random sample of size $n$, I'm looking for something like

$|| \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \theta_i ||_2 \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and possibly $\sigma^2 \to 0$

Intuitively, the vectors are orthogonal so they pull in different directions and when you average a lot of them they generally don't go anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should probably try to clean up the question a bit: I guess you are talking about random variables, realizations are numbers, not vectors, the $\|\ldots \|_2$ should maybe be just $|\ldots |$ (sum of numbers is a number) etc... It is also not fully clear what is "orthogonal" and in which sense.

Comment: Now I'm confused. The $\theta$s are vectors. I'm talking about pearson correlation, which can be viewed as the cosine of the angle between two vectors.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm confused as well. If $\theta_i$ are just vectors and correlation is just some formula, then I don't understand what does it mean that $corr\simeq \mathcal{N}$. I would somehow think of $\theta_i$ an $n$-sample realized from some random variable $X_i$ but I'm not sure

Comment: Ok then I guess you're right, the $\theta$s are random vectors, and then we can talk about both their dot products (angles between them) and their expectations.

Comment: In any case  -- don't you assume that $\theta_i$ has each zero mean (whatever it is)? Because otherwise, there is no reason why the mean of those $\theta_i$'s (whatever they are) should go to zero.

Comment: Right. That's what I was missing, thanks.